# Asp.net Identity: change user role while logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

I have a page where a logged-in user performs an action and based on that I change the user's role like this:

```
    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
    var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

    IdentityUser user = manager.FindById(TheMembershipID);

    manager.RemoveFromRole(user.Id, "StartUser");
    manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "AppUser");
```

Then, on the client, there's a redirect to another page that requires authentication in the AppUser role. The problem is that the user shows as being still logged in as a StartUser.

How do I change the role of a user while he's logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to log them out and back in for the new role to take effect.  After  your code:

```
//Get the authentication manager
var authenticationManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;

//Log the user out
authenticationManager.SignOut();

//Log the user back in
var identity = manager.CreateIdentity(user,DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationManager.SignIn(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true}, identity);
```

This isn't exact, but should give you the general idea.